# Removing a word from a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html on a page:

```
<h1 class="theme-color-3">Knowledge Portal Site</h1>
```

This is rendered dynamically.I dont want the word Site after 'Knowledge Portal'.I dont know where the word Site is hardcoded,so i wrote the following jquery code to remove that word.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1.theme-color-3').html($('h1.theme-color-3').html().replace('Site',''));

});
```

But the problem is that because this code executes only after the whole page has finished loading,the word Site shows for some time and then disappears.
Is there a way to prevent that ?

Thank You

Comment: 1. You should use `text()` instead of `html()` if you are dealing with text only. 2. What do you do if users have JS disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Place a `<script>` element right after the `<h1>` element, like so:

```
<h1 class="theme-color-3">Knowledge Portal Site</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('h1.theme-color-3').text($('h1.theme-color-3').text().replace('Site',''));
</script>
```

This will ensure the script is processed immediately after the element is parsed, so make sure the jQuery script is in the `<head>` or at least further up the document.  Also, use `text()` instead of `html()` if you're not applying HTML.  It's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the element to `display:none`, but that would leave those with javascript turned off without the element at all.

Basically there is no good solution.